# adding node at ith position

Tags: c++, nodes

I want to create a link list with a size of 5 and add some nodes at ith position.

I will add the nodes at random position say (0, 5 and 2) of the link list.

this is what it looks like adding the node at position 0.

```
      0
 +---------+
 |    1    |
 +---------+ --> NULL
 |  next   | 
 +---------+
```

this is what it looks like adding the node at position 5.

```
      0             1             2             3             4
 +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
 |    1    |   |  Empty  |   |  Empty  |   |  Empty  |   |    2    |
 +---------+-------------------------------------------->+---------+-->NULL
 |  next   |   |  node   |   |  node   |   |  node   |   |  next   |
 +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
```

so node 1,2,3 is empty and 0 is linked to 4.

this is what it looks like adding the node at position 1.

```
      0             1             2             3             4 
 +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
 |    1    |   |    2    |   |  Empty  |   |  Empty  |   |    2    |
 +---------+-->+---------+------------------------------>+---------+-->NULL
 |  next   |   |  next   |   |  node   |   |  node   |   |  next   |
 +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
```

so node 2,3 is empty and 0 is linked to 1 and 1 is linked to 4.

I tried to implement it but it's not printing anything. Please advise. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int x;
    node *next;
};

node * head = NULL;
node * newNode;
node * temp;

void addNode(int pos, int size)
{
    /*if head is null, initialize a new node
      set data = 1 for head;
    */
    if(head == NULL && pos == 0)
    {
        newNode = new node;
        head = newNode;
        head->x = 1;
        temp = head;
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         Adding a node at ith position.
         1. check if the the position is less than the size of the link list.
         2. set the temp position to be 0(head)
         3. use the temp pointer and go to the ith postion.
         4. create new node at ith position.
         5. set data = 2 for the node at ith position.
     */
        if (pos < size)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
            {
                temp = head;
                temp = temp->next;

                if (pos == i)
                {
                    newNode = new node;
                    temp = newNode;
                    temp->x = 2;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Print() {
    while(head->next != NULL)
    {
        std::cout<< head->x << std::endl;
        head=head->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "1. Add Node and Print " << std::endl;

        std::cin >> input;
        switch ( input ) {
            case 1:
                addNode(0, 5);
                addNode(5, 5);
                addNode(1, 5);
                Print();
                break;
            default:
                std::cout<<"Bad Input";
                break;
        }
        std::cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what is `Empty`; atm when you try to add new nodes, the iterator ( `temp` ) will hit null and then try to dereference it..

Comment: so I can I add a node at ith position then? if I add at a new node at positon 0 and then later at position 5, then to me, the position of the nodes from  2-4 will be "empty". that's how I see it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you would have to define some symbolic value for `Empty` and then create new nodes along the way ( where they are null )..  most people treat linked list with only add to tail functions instead of position - do you need to set the position ?

Comment: yes I need to set the position

Comment: try moving the assignment `temp = head;` outside of the loop ( should be set at the start ), and add some logic in the loop to iterate temp and insert nodes with `Empty` where they're null

Comment: I guess I have to iterate the temp using for loop. and Inside the for loop, I have to do something like temp->next to get to the location. but I am not sure how can I insert node with "Empty" when they're null. do you might showing me how to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77388/discussion-between-amdixon-and-user3429531).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I undestand your question you want to write function that will set value of the node at specified index and if index in larger than current size of the list it will automatically extend your list. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

It is easy enough. You need to iterate through your list while counter `i` (see the code below) is less than specified position. If list is smaller, than you create node and mark their value as some certain value `EMPTY`. When counter is equals to position, then set value of node to `value`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    int   data;
    node* next;
};

#define EMPTY -1

node * head = NULL;

void setNode(int pos, int value) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new node;
        head->data = EMPTY;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    node* p = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        if(p->next == NULL) {
            p->next = new node;
            p->next->data = EMPTY;
            p->next->next = NULL;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->data = value;
}

void print() {
    node* p = head;
    while(p != NULL) {
        std::cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    setNode(0, 1);
    setNode(5, 2);
    setNode(1, 3);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Also in your code there were mistakes in print function:

1. You changed `head` variable.
2. And the last value of the list was not printed, because of the condition in `while` loop.